# Merging another web.php file in config/web.php of yii2

Tags: web, include, yii2, yii2-basic-app

We are two groups developing a project made in Yii2 basic. The problem we are facing right now is we have different `web.php` under `config`. Our group would like to include our `web.php` (which was renamed to `extras.php`) inside the `web.php` of another group. The difference is we added variables under `components` of `$config` of `web.php`. Yes, we can manually add our new variables under `components` of `$config` from the other team but we prefer to use separate files that is why we renamed the other `web.php` to `extras.php`.

A small preview of web.php looks like this

```
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'language'=>  isset($_SESSION['language_local']) ? $_SESSION['language_local']:'en',
    'components' => [
        'nagios' => [
                    'class' =>  'app\components\nagios',
        ],
        'hostlistsql' => [
                   'class' =>  'app\components\hostlistsql',
        ],
        'request' => [empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'nYwdMpu-dw004qwFRZmqZOzzC3xdnL8b',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

extras.php looks like this

```
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'language'=>  isset($_SESSION['language_local']) ? $_SESSION['language_local']:'en',
    'components' => [
        'user_functions' => [
                    'class' =>  'app\components\UserFunctions',
        ],
        'user_extras' => [
                   'class' =>  'app\components\UserExtras',
        ],
        'request' => [empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'nYwdMpu-dw004qwFRZmqZOzzC3xdnL8b',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

What approach should we take to include `extras.php` inside `web.php`?

EDIT:

SOLUTION:
Inside `web/index.php` has

```
$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');
```

I changed it instead to

```
$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/extras.php')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to include extras.php inside web.php instead of just merging them?

Here is how the same thing is handled in yii2 advanced https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/environments/dev/frontend/web/index.php

As you can see common..main.php is merged with common..main-local.php is merged with frontend..main.php is merged with frontend..main-local.php

There are 4 files that are merged to get to the end 1 single config file. Eazy as pie.

If you really want to merge things inside web.php do a

```
$config = [....];
return yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    $config,
    require(__DIR__ . 'extras.php'),
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this idea! I almost lost hope with this one but the link you provided helped me also a lot. I modified `web/index.php` instead of `config/web.php`

Comment: yep, that would be my choice too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you guys have any version control system (like git, Bitbucket, etc...) ?
You could let only the things you have in common in the `web.php` file and the rest coming from a external file.

Since each group will have a different file, i would recommend create a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) that decides which file is being used. Following your example:

**web.php:**

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'language'=>  isset($_SESSION['language_local']) ? $_SESSION['language_local']:'en',
    'components' => EXTRAS ? require(__DIR__ . '/components2.php') : require(__DIR__ . '/components1.php'),
    'params' => require(__DIR__ . '/params.php')
];
```

**Example of components2.php:**

```
return [
    'user_functions' => [
                'class' =>  'app\components\UserFunctions',
    ],
    'user_extras' => [
               'class' =>  'app\components\UserExtras',
    ],
    'request' => [empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'nYwdMpu-dw004qwFRZmqZOzzC3xdnL8b',
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ]
]
```

And `EXTRAS` is a constant defined elsewhere. You could do that in `web/index.php` (follow the `YII_DEBUG` and `YII_ENV` samples) and add it in your ignored files, if you didn't already.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but choosing between two components will not help to our goal.